# How to access a part of the context state without rendering each time the global changes?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I have the next question...

**Would it be possible to share a state part that is in context, consumed in a particular child without rendering it every time the whole state changes and not this part? (Without passing it through props)**

And this is an example of code (using props) but instead, I want to use a "useContext of a state part" without rendering every time the global context changes:

**container.tsx**

```
export const App: React.FunctionComponent<AppContextProps> = props => {
  const [appState, appDispatch] = React.useReducer(reducer, initialAppState);

  return (
    <>
      <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        <>
          <GlobalStyle />
          <AppDispatch.Provider value={appDispatch}>
            <FixedBottomContainer
              bookForm={<BookForm />}
              listContainer={
                <ListContainer
                  books={appState.books}
                  discount={appState.discount}
                />
              }
              discountContainer={
                <DiscountContainer discount={appState.discount} />
              }
            />
          </AppDispatch.Provider>
        </>
      </ThemeProvider>
    </>
  );
};
```

**DiscountContainer.tsx**

```
export const DiscountContainer: React.FunctionComponent<
  DiscountContainerProps
> = ({ discount }) => {
  const appDispatch = React.useContext(AppDispatch);

  const handleDiscount = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) =>
    appDispatch({ type: "addDiscount", payload: event.target.value });

  return (
    <>
      <StyledDiscountField value={discount} onChange={handleDiscount} />
    </>
  );
};
```

Thanks in advance!

Best,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately no.

React docs say:

> All consumers that are descendants of a Provider will re-render whenever the Provider’s value prop changes.

As soon as part of the global state changes a whole state becomes a different object because we do not mutate existing state but copy the old one and make changes we need to get a new one (immutability in action).

That said, you still can create several contexts. Like in your example create `BooksContext`, `DiscountContext`.

Have a look at Kent Dodds nice [blog post](https://kentcdodds.com/blog/application-state-management-with-react) about state management in React.

Comment: Thank you very much, I'll take a look at that article I haven't seen :)

Answer (score 1):

Are you running into some kind of severe performance bottleneck caused by unnecessary renders? That is typically the only reason you should care about that kind of optimization. Try not to prematurely optimize React when you don't have to - it's really not worth it. The cost of doing a render is minuscule because React itself is so well optimized. And ideally your app is written such that "extra" renders will not change *how* it functions.

If you insist, though, you can look into [React.Memo](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo), which is a functional component that only re-renders if the props change.